# Utilizar o like no método findby para filtrar registros?

Tags: doctrine, symfony-2

Tenho o seguinte código no meu controller:

```
$shares = $this
    ->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Shares')
    ->findBy(
        $where,
        $orderBy,
        $paginator->getPerPage(),
        $paginator->getCursor()
    )
;
```

Repare que tenho como parâmetro a variável `where` para o método `findby`.

A variável `where` é um array:

```
$where['hashtags'] = "teste";
```

O problema é que na entidade `Shares`, o campo `hashtags` é um array:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 */
protected $hashtags;
```

Na base de dados fica gravado da seguinte forma:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:5:"teste";i:1;s:9:"bubbletea";}
```

Como faço para pesquisar todos os registros que possuem no campo `hashtags` a tag "teste" utilizando a função `findby`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu já trabalhei com um sistema parecido com o seu (em que eu gravava um vetor de valores no banco de dados por meio do Doctrine, que por sua vez o armazenava como um vetor serializado), e a no final das contas tive que normalizar a tabela de tags.

Por que? Porque a busca na coluna de tags performava muito mal – afinal, estamos fazendo uma busca por um string que pode estar localizado em qualquer parte da string.

Se você quiser aproveitar a solução, acredito que a solução seja algo do tipo:

```
$shares = $this
    ->getDoctrine()
    ->getManager()
    ->createQuery('
        SELECT s
        FROM AppBundle:Shares s
        WHERE s.hashtags LIKE :hashtag')
    ->setParameter('hashtag', '%"' . $hashtag . '"%')
    ->setMaxResults($paginator->getPerPage())
    ->setFirstResult($paginator->getCursor())
    ->getResult();
```

Agora, se você prefere (e pode) mudar para uma abordagem mais performática, eu criaria uma relação n-para-n entre os shares e as hashtags, e faria a busca na tabela de hashtags a fim de descobrir quais shares possuem aquelas hashtags.

Com essa abordagem, você ainda pode criar um índice na coluna de hashtags, o que faria com que a busca ficasse ainda mais rápida.

Comment: Realmente a ideia de serializar não foi a das melhores ainda mais porque toda a aplicação gira em torno das tags, entretanto a solução funcionou. Vou alterar e adicionar uma relação ManyToMany. Obrigado pela ajuda.